# Electrical shower no water pressure after turning off the mains supply

Tags: water, water-pressure

Hi I am hoping someone can help me - I turned my water supply off and replaced two ballcocks - one for heating and one on my main tank - drained all water out of the system - turned supply back on water flowed perfect. I have 2 electrical shower both off the mains water supply. One shower works as expected - however my second one doesnt work in fact there is not water supply getting to it at all and doesnt work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what an electrical shower is, but it sounds terrifying.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It sounds like one of the "point of use" showers - fed with cold water and has an in-built heater (needs a large electrical supply, usually on its own breaker)... quite common in some markets.

Comment: This sounds like you have an air-lock somewhere - turning taps on and off may cause the water to push through... Have the shower tap open...

Comment: @jphi it means an on-demand heater dedicated to the shower.